# How do I scroll horizontally through a Sketch canvas like Illustrator does?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, shortcuts

In Illustrator you have the very handy CTRL+mouse scroll shortcut to quickly scroll horizontally through your canvas. I want to do the same in Sketch (not necessarily with the same shortcuts).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I find the quickest, most efficient way to scroll horizontally is to:

Hold spacebar, then click and drag the canvas (in any direction).

Alternatively, if you get/have a mouse with a thumbwheel you can assign that to horizontal scrolling.

If you are using a trackpad, you can use a two-finger drag/swipe to move the canvas in any direction.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can move from artboard to artboard in sequence by holding the <kbd>FN</kbd> key (on Mac) and pressing the left or right arrow.  This is good for doing quick presentations of designs or flows on artboards.